# Is there a Java API for GCM Cloud Connection Server

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am just going through the new features of GCM Cloud connection server. On client side this seems fairly easy using the google play services, as described in https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html, however for the server side it says:

> GCM Cloud Connection Server (CCS) is an XMPP endpoint, running on
>   http://gcm.googleapis.com port 5235.
>
> CCS requires a Transport Layer Security (TLS) connection. That means
>   the XMPP client must initiate a TLS connection. For example in smack,
>   you would call setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory), similar to “old
>   style SSL” XMPP connections and https.
>
> CCS requires a SASL PLAIN authentication mechanism using
>   @gcm.googleapis.com (GCM sender ID) and the API
>   key as the password, where the sender ID and API key are the same as
>   described in Getting Started.

Does that mean I manually have to open a port and parse xml/json or is there some kind of Java API that I can use to implement the server side?

Answer (score 2):

For the GCM Server there is a library, the javadoc is at http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/server/package-summary.html

There is a demo server app Google has written here at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

As I understand you can choose whether you want to use the XMPP service or the old HTTP service. Not sure what the advantage is.

Comment: I know the example for the GCM Server, but I am asking for an API for the CCS server.

Comment: The advantage is mainly performance and two-way communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) library to work with XMPP in Java.
And [here](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-ccs-with-xmpp/) you can find an example code that sends notifications using GCM CCS.